# How to solve $y''=\sqrt{1-(y')^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the following differential equation

$$ y''=\sqrt{1-(y')^2} $$

So far in my course I've seen the Picard process, the separable equations and now I have absolutely no idea how to solve this problem, I would like to have some hints. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $z=y'$ implies

$$z' = \sqrt{1-z^2}$$
$$\dfrac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}} = dx$$
$$\int_{z_0}^{z}\dfrac{d\bar{z}}{\sqrt{1-\bar{z}^2}} = x - x_0$$
$$\arcsin z - \arcsin z_0 = x - x_0$$
$$z(x) = \sin(x- x_0 + \arcsin z_0)$$

Now, solve $y'(x) = z(x)$ by integration.
Can you solve it from here?

Answer (score 2):

Seing the equation as one in $y'$, it is separable and integrates as

$$\arcsin(y')=x+c$$ or $$y'=\sin(x+c).$$

Then

$$y=c'-\cos(x+c).$$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{y''}{\sqrt{1-y'^2}}=1$, therefore $\arcsin y'-\arcsin y'(0)=t$, therefore $y'=\sin(t+\arcsin y'(0))$, therefore \begin{align}y&=y(0)-\cos(t+\arcsin y'(0))+\cos\arcsin y'(0)=\\&=y(0)+\sqrt{1-y'(0)^2}(1-\cos t)+y'(0)\sin t\end{align}